# Dynamic height for custom app

Tags: javascript, rally, appsdk2

I've noticed that some of the *out of the box* Rally apps change their height dynamically based on the amount of data taking up vertical space. I would like the same functionality for my custom apps but it seems as though setting a fixed or *auto* (height of the screen) are my only options. Is there a layout setting that will allow me to have the app change its height automatically, or a function to set the height by hand?

Thanks!

Comment: When I install the portfolio kanban app, for example, its height extends to contain all the content.  However, if I take the source code from github and put it into a custom html app, the height is limited.  Is this some setting for the iframe of a custom html app vs rally apps?

Comment: You have it correct. User apps are hosted in IFrames therefore have a static size. If you wanted to be really devious you could reach out of your iframe and change the size of your container.

Answer (score 0):

In some of out of box Rally apps it is done internally, but there is no layout setting that will allow users to have the app change its height automatically,and there is no function available to set the height by hand.